# A question about the minimum blossom temperature of fruit trees and shrubs

Tags: planting-times

I am making a webapplication for gardeneres that comes with a few tools. One of which is to be able to automatically create a planting calendar that is based on the monthly average temperature curve of the user who is requesting the planting calendar.

To create this personalized planting calendar the application takes in account 3 things. 
1. Minimum germination temperature
2. Days until maturity (harvest)
3. minimum required chill hours for the plant to bear fruit (if applicable).

During the creation of the planting calendar the application retrieves all the plant rows in the database 
that can be grown in a particular month and it also checks if the temperatures in the months after the start month are high enough to let the plant develop to maturity.

This works fine for annuals that require sowing seed or planting bulbs, but it does not work well for plants that might require multiple years to develop from seed to plant, like shrubs and trees.

So instead of the minimum germination temperature i want to use the minimum blossom temperature of the tree/shrub and the amount of days it takes for a flower to go to a fruit/vegetable. If the plant does not flower then it should be the minimum temperature for fruit setting.

My question is: How can i best define minimum blossom or fruitset temperature? Should it be equal to the temperature on the day the first flowerbud blossoms, or the first fruit start is setting or should it be more like the average temperature of the days before the flower started blossoming? If so, on how many days should the average temperature be based on?

Thank you

Comment: Too complicated for me to work out, there is so much variability year on year, depending on light and moisture levels as well as temperature, but I would just point out that, in your penultimate paragraph, last sentence, you say 'if the plant does not flower... it should be the min temp for fruit setting'. Note that a plant cannot produce fruit I(or seed) of any sort UNLESS it  flowers.

Comment: @Bamboo, pine trees don't flower, yet they produce seeds

Comment: Not a flower as such because they are gymnosperms, but they produce male and female cones - the male cone pollinates the female ones so viable seed can be produced. The process is the same, its just the female parts are not enclosed in an ovary.  Presumably, gymnosperms are not of much interest for your app, since its focused on harvests?

Comment: @Bamboo the app is focused on anything edible, the seeds from the pine tree can be roasted and used in salads. Hope to have it completed between today and june the fifth

Comment: True, completely forgot about pine nuts, which I eat a lot of! But pollination still has to occur to get those 'fruits'...